# Problem with installing ADT Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, installation

So, I "searched for new software" under the `help`-tag, downloaded the files from the provided link, let Eclipse do the rest until i could click "finish" and finally restarted Eclipse.

During the installation-progress, Eclipse asked me if I trusted a certain certificate that was downloaded. I guess that is normal.

After the restart of Eclipse, I couldn't find an `"Android"`-Tag in `Window/Preferences`. It was simply not there! I uninstalled Eclipse once and reinstalled it, made all the steps again and finally restarted Eclipse again, but it was still not there! I couldn't add the ADT-Plugin to Eclipse.

I'm using the most recent Eclipse.

(I do already see the DDMS perspective and can activate it somehow :O)

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the Android SDK before the eclipse ADT plugin? If not then install the SDK. Here is a link to the [installer.](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r11-windows.exe)